# Pyspark sql for oracle subquery

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

How to write following oracle based sql query into equivalent pyspark sql as this is not supported as it is due to nesting under spark.sql(*query)
Is there any way to write this using pyspark dataframe too ?

```
SELECT TABLE1.COL1 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE COL2 = (
    SELECT MAX(COL2) 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE TABLE1.COL3 = TABLE2.COL3 OR TABLE1.COL4 = TABLE2.COL4
)
```

TABLE1 has columns `COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4`
TABLE2 has columns `COL3, COL4`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this syntax, if you use a JDBC driver :

```
  sql_request = "(select TABLE1.COL1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL2 = (SELECT MAX(COL2) FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.COL3 = TABLE2.COL3 OR TABLE1.COL4 = TABLE2.COL4))"

  df_request = spark.read.jdbc(url=url,table=sql_request,properties=db_properties)
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Is there any way to do using pyspark sql or pyspark dataframe ?

Comment: Maybe I can suggest these links: https://www.realdbamagic.com/spark-sql-and-oracle-database-integration/ or https://medium.com/@usmanazhar4/how-to-read-and-write-from-database-in-spark-using-pyspark-150d39cdbb72 or https://gokhanatil.com/2018/04/pyspark-examples-3-4-spark-sql-module.html  to start ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max

table1.select(table1.COL1)\
  .where(table1.COL2 == table2.select(max(table2.COL2).alias('MAX_COL2'))\
      .where((table1.COL3 == table2.COL3) | (table1.COL4 == table2.COL4)).collect().head().MAX_COL2).show()
```

Hope this can help.